# What is the white building pictured in the San Francisco (21043) set?

Tags: model-identification, architecture

Can someone help identify what the red-circled building is (not the cylindrical Coit Tower) in this [set](https://shop.lego.com/en-US/product/San-Francisco-21043)?  The others are obvious, but this one does not seem to be identified in any of the official literature.

[image: sfskyline]

Comment: [jangbricks](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=YVPcMe3OCt0) mentions *650 California Street* in his review...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it is 50 Fremont Center/Salesforce West Tower (it's right in front of/besides Salesforce Tower);
[image]

I acknowledge that the scale seems off. I'm guessing it is the Fremont Center based on it's location, appearance, and that Lego didn't bother labeling it, as if Salesforce West is part of Salesforce Tower. Also, if you were to look at Salesforce Tower from Coit Tower, the white buildings position is pretty much right on (if other buildings weren't blocking your view).
  Additionally, none of the landmarks or their proximity to each other are really on scale in this Lego set.  I feel like it's more of a representation than a model.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a view from satellite photo:

[image: 50 Fremont Center San Francisco]

Answer (score 3):

So it's **Salesforce West Tower**. Or is it?

- Here's the heights, according to wikipedia.

[image]

Seems like the proportions are good. Except for Salesforce West Tower. At 600 ft it should be almost half the size of Salesforce Tower. How odd.

- Here's a photo from the instructions booklet.

[image]

Notice the building with the pyramid roof (yellow arrow) and the two white ones next to it.

- Here's the same view from above.

[image]

Turns out that the white building is Steuart Tower, height 364 ft. That's to scale.

Steuart Tower, however, is home to the [Autodesk Gallery](https://www.autodesk.com/gallery/overview) that features an 8.5-foot, 62,500 LEGO piece dinosaur in their [exhibition](https://www.autodesk.com/gallery/exhibits/currently-on-display/lego).

So something makes me believe that this small white building is in fact: *an easter egg!*

And I think **it's One Market Plaza, Steuart Tower**.

What do you think? Am I wrong?

Comment: If you are correct, it seems odd that they wouldn't have built more of the building since Steuart Tower is actually part of a 3 building complex, all very much connected. An easter egg is a much cooler idea, I wonder if we'll ever know?

Comment: Based on the proportions, I really think it’s the Gateway apartments.

Answer (score 1):

That’s either the Embarcadero Center (one of the four in a row seen at image below)  or it is the Gateway apartments (visible in front of the row of four).

[image]

Source ([Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Embarcadero_Center_(5028766029)_(cropped).jpg))

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks a little like 650 Calfornia (right up the hill from the B of A building)…

Comment: Could you add a picture of the building you've mentioned? This would greatly improve the quality of your answer.